# Pycharm - any way to add code completion hints for config or custom nested dict?

Tags: pycharm, yaml

I have a YAML config file with lots of nested parameters that I read into my_config.
To make coding easier I am also using Python-box to allow me to use dot notation as in 
mock_mode = my_config.default.mock_mode

The code works fine but I would like to have autocompletion hints particularly for the deeply nested parameters.
I was hoping that if I set a breakpoint after my_config is populated and then break there in debug mode that I could write code using my_config and Pycharm would then know and list the parameter tree when I type the first . after myconfig but it does not do so.

I have enabled 'Collect runtime types information for code insight' and am using Kite but neither help.

Are there any tricks to make Pycharm aware of my config structure?

```
from box import Box
import yaml

with open('config.yml') as f:
    config_dict = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    config_box = Box(config_dict)

    # I now want to add more code  - e.g choose gateway from list of config parameters
    gateway = config_box.ip_settings.      
    # code completion popup on hitting period shows few things but not keys from config_box
```

Answer (score 0):

add these two plugins to your IDE:

[Yaml](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13126-yaml)

[Yaml-Config Autocomplete](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12016-yaml-config-autocomplete)